# Pycharm com sublinhado no código

Tags: pycharm

Estou usando a aparencia dracula no pycharm o problema que meu comentarios ficam com linhas sublinhadas como se fosse correção automatica do word(odeio isso) com codigos grandes isso é mt chato. Alguem sabe retira-los?

---

ainda persiste a dúvida.......[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não to vendo nenhum sublinhado na imagem acima, poderia indicar onde ocorre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File->Settings->Inspections

Spelling, desmarcar a opção Typo.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81334)

Comment: Como isso não responde a pergunta? São os passos no menu do pycharm pra tirar a verificação ortográfica (estilo word)

Answer (score 0):

no pycharm 2020.2
File / Settings / Inspections / Proofreading / Typo, desmarque esta opção e seja feliz. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

São avisos do editor, no seu comentário deixe um espaço entre a  '#' (cerquilha) e o comentário. Ficaria assim:  # inicio do comentário, esses avisos são  para deixar seu codigo sempre com mesmo padrão. 
Espero ter ajudado.